# Pivot the dates based on event/status values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have data like below for a SQL query and want to convert that as below where 106 is event start and 110 is event end date.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if there are consecutive records with `106` or `110`?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2029983)

Comment: Here is the code

Comment: GMB...... that will not be the case where we will see consecutive records with 106 or 110

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence of records is always `106/110` for each `(orders_sk_seq, order_product_sk_seq)` tuple, then you can just use `lead()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        orders_sk_seq, 
        order_product_sk, 
        create_datetime start_date,
        status_code,
        lead(create_datetime) over(
            partition by orders_sk_seq, order_product_sk_seq order by create_datetime
        ) end_date
    from mytable
) t
where status_code = 106
order by start_date
```

Comment: What if we have other status codes in between then also it will work.

Comment: @VIJAYSHARMA: it depends, you would need to show relevant sample data for that, along with an explanation of the expected result. But as for the question that you have asked, remember you said: *that will not be the case where we will see consecutive records with 106 or 110*...

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Order_CTE AS
    (
    SELECT order_Product_sk_seq,status_code,create_datetime
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_Product_sk_seq,status_code ORDER BY create_datetime) AS SEQUENCE
    FROM atclose.order_status
    where status_code IN (106,110)
    )

SELECT 
 b1.order_Product_sk_seq
,b1.create_datetime
,b2.create_datetime
FROM Order_CTE b1
        JOIN (
                 SELECT 
                      order_Product_sk_seq
                     ,create_datetime
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_Product_sk_seq ORDER BY create_datetime) AS SEQUENCE
                FROM atclose.order_status
                WHERE status_code = 110) b2 
    ON b1.order_Product_sk_seq = b2.order_Product_sk_seq
     AND b1.Sequence = b2.Sequence
WHERE b1.status_code = 106;
```